# Python while true Condition throws syntax errors

Tags: python

Could you please advise what is wrong with the below code please?

```
def add(x, y):
   return x + y
while True:
    try:
        num1 = float(input('Enter first number: ')
    except:
        print ('num1 is a complex/string. Only Integers or Float is allowed. Please key in again')
    try:
        num2 = float(input("Enter first number: ")
    except:
        print ('num2 is a complex/string. Only Integers or Float is allowed. Please key in again')
    break
print(num1,"+",num2,"=", add(num1,num2))
input("Press enter to exit ;)")
```

Comment: You didn't close your parentheses. Two opening parentheses need two closing parentheses.

Comment: There are multiple issues in your code. Why not try running it and see what errors are produced. Typically the message will direct you towards the actual problem. Learning to debug code a step at a time is an important skill. Much more than just finding an answer to making some code work. Your investment in time will pay off as time goes on.

Comment: Thanks all for your brilliant suggestion and help. It worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 1):

*(apart from the syntax errors - missing brackets...)*

The `break` statement escapes the while loop, so by putting it at the end of the iteration, you will break out on the very first iteration so if the enter invalid inputs, they won't be asked again since you will have broken out.

In addition, the logic is wrong in terms of having only one loop. If they enter a valid `num1` and then an invalid `num2`, they will (if you move the `break`) be asked to enter both `num1` and `num2` again - rather than just `num2` again.

To remedy these issues, you could compartmentalise your code - moving the inputting logic to a function:

```
def get_float(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return float(input(prompt))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('sorry, invalid input')
```

Then your main code is much easier to understand:

```
def add(x, y):
   return x + y

num1 = get_float('Enter first number: ')
num2 = get_float('Enter second number: ')
result = add(num1, num2)
print(num1, '+', num2, '=', result)
input('press enter to exit')
```

---

And a trial run shows its good:

```
Enter first number: one
sorry, invalid input
Enter first number: bob
sorry, invalid input
Enter first number: 20
Enter second number: nine
sorry, invalid input
Enter second number: 8.89
20.0 + 8.89 = 28.89
press enter to exit
```

Comment: pressing enter on input will generate an error.  You should not be using input in python 2.7 unless you want python code to run.

Comment: @eatmeimadanish this is python3 code, python 2.7 is largely outdated, most new python questions on SO are python 3

Comment: That's not true at all.  Python 2.7 is still faster than 3, and is still being updated, and still used more than python 3. https://rushter.com/blog/python-3-adoption/

Comment: @eatmeimadanish Read the *ps* of that article: "p.s. There is no reason to use Python 2 in the upcoming year and I'm not advocating it."! Nevertheless, I did not state that Python 3 was more widely in use or even that it was faster (which I can't say I've heard of before), I merely stated that it is the advised version to learn by many different sources and it is rightfully the most asked about version on SO in recent times.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use raw_input to accept just an enter prompt.

```
def add(x, y):
   return x + y
while True:
    try:
        num1 = float(raw_input('Enter first number: '))
    except:
        print ('num1 is a complex/string. Only Integers or Float is allowed. Please key in again')
    try:
        num2 = float(raw_input("Enter second number: "))
    except:
        print ('num2 is a complex/string. Only Integers or Float is allowed. Please key in again')
    break
print(num1,"+",num2,"=", add(num1,num2))

raw_input("Press enter to exit ;)")
```